# How would transitive functional dependencies occur here?

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

so im reading up on database normalization, and it seems like for the most part, a lot of us are already following up to 2NF or even 3NF without realizing it. I wonder why our professor 4 years ago told us thats a topic discussed in masters database course because its "too complicated" lol...sounds straight forward to me really...

anyways, part of [this article here](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html), talks about 3NF, and to achieve that, you need to have 2NF and no no transitive functional dependencies.

the example given is this image, but i dont understand...how could a value of a non-key column change a value of another non-key column? if anything, it sounds to me like a glitch in the system if that were to happen...

Consider the table 1. Changing the non-key column Full Name may change Salutation.

[image: norm]

Comment: I don't know why 3NF would be described as "too complicated".  The principle "store data once and put it in the appropriate entity" seems pretty simple to me.  Admittedly, it does have some repurcussions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ya, actually, the entire normalization topic was considered "too complicated" for undergrad students at the time. so being naive CS student that i was at the time, i just rolled along with what we were told and didnt bother exploring it because i thought it was a PHD topic or something. the things you learn ....

Comment: . . I find that the academic treatment of it is rather overly complicated.  Show students some examples of the right way to structure a database; explain the key principles; give them homework on how to fix some problems.  Then test'em.  I find the treatment of 1NF, 2NF and so on is a bit abstract from the perspective of actual database design.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i kid you not, all i recall ever learning in the database class was theories and mathematics. the actual implementation and practically building a database? nope, we were on our own. i wish he showed us the tools we needed to get started, and the different databases that exist and actually showed us examples. the whole time it was just theoretical, and i found the primary key/foreign key/composite key concept so confusing that i didnt understand it until i had to implement it at work. its so simple but they make things so complex, rediculous

Comment: . . I guess I'm lucky.  I learned about databases by having to build one -- and then another -- from scratch.  The only part of the theory that resonates is the algorithms and complexity for the underlying algorithms.

Comment: Hi. There are problems with addressing presentations in SO questions. A question should be self-contained. So this should quote what is needed from that link to ask your question. ([Using text, not images/links, for text--including tables.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)) The question you are asking doesn't make sense, "how could a value of a non-key column change a value of another non-key column?" You need to give enough context. Although  that presentation is full of wrong things & is missing things & it's not clear.

Comment: I see that you are more or less quoting the presentation & asking what it is trying to say. It's badly written, and trying to give an example of something that is not so. Explaining what it is trying to say is not helpful because the whole presentation is wrong & unclear. But if you had researched to make sense of it before considering asking here then you would have come across definitions that show this presentation says wrong things & leaves out things & is incoherent. That article is worthless. (So are statements like "store data once and put it in the appropriate entity".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article is terrible. So clearly some people find it difficult to understand normalisation. (Many people struggle with the difference between 3NF vs Boyce-Codd NF, which the article ducks out of explaining.) The article says

> Normalization helps produce database systems that are cost-effective and have better security models.

That's not the chief reason for normalising a design. Indeed in the early days of the Relational Model (when disk was expensive, so for example dates had two-digit years), normalisation (i.e. vertical partitioning) was the opposite of cost-effective, and a lot of attention was paid to trade-offs in (partially) denormalised schemas.

The chief reason for normalisation is to avoid duplicating information and/or duplicates getting out of step, called 'update anomalies'. Specifically:

> A transitive functional dependency is when changing a non-key column, might cause any of the other non-key columns to change

Is a terrible way to put it. But might mean: when you update one column (`Full Name`) of one row (`Membership Id` 3) you need to also update other column(s) (`Salutation`) of the same or other row(s) (`Membership Id` 2?); or if you don't, you break the consistency of the data.

The article doesn't tell us what FDs are expected to hold. Does `Full Name` determine `Salutation`? Is it possible the `Membership ID` 3 `Robert Phil` could qualify as a Doctor and therefore change his `Salutation` without `Member` 2 also becoming a Doctor? Then there is no FD from `Full Name` to `Salutation`, and what looks like duplicated entry is not.

Presumably what the example is trying to show (I'm not sure, because it's wrong) is that there's a dependency between `Full Name` and `Salutation`. Introducing a `Salutation Id` is so ... stupid, I'm very tempted to say "not even wrong". It has not removed the Transitive Functional Dependency at all.

Normalisation would (assuming there is a FD from `Full Name` to `Salutation`):

- Put `Full Name` and `Salutation` in a separate table, keyed by `Full Name` -- that represents one of the FDs.
- Remove `Salutation` from the `Membership` table.
- Not introduce a `Salutation ID` field.
- You can recover the original `Membership` table by joining to the `Full Name, Salutation` table.

The alleged 3NF form has not removed the Transitive Functional Dependency, and so is not in 3NF. All it has done is replace a Transitive FD from `Membership ID` to `Full Name` to `Salutation` with one from `Membership ID` to `Full Name` to `Salutation ID`. So if `Member` 3 changes their name from `Robert Phil` to `Roberta Phil`, under the initial design `Salutation` would have to change in step from `Mr` to `Ms`; under the alleged 3NF design *still* the `Salutation ID` has to change from `1` to `2`.

There are other reasons to think that alleged 3NF design is not 3NF. I expect a dependency from Person to `Full Name` and to `Address`. There's no column `Person`, with the consequence there are two `Mr Robert Phil`s. Are they the same person? Then what if they flatted together? The article tries to introduce a composite key `{Full Name, Address}`, but that won't help; and it's quite common for same-named father and son to live at the same address. We'd have two people with same name at same address. (What  if one of them then qualified as a Doctor?)

Normalisation would introduce a `Person ID`, key to a `Person` table, with columns `Full Name`, `Salutation`, `Address`. The partitioned `Membership` table would have columns `Membership ID` (key), `Person ID` (Foreign Key references `Person`).

Comment: I see, thank you for the detailed breakdown! Now I understand,  so its basically like saying: person -> full name , fullname->salutation, person ->salutation is a functional dependency, so in order to normalize it in 3NF, partition the table into a person table, and membership table, in which then link them by the person ID PK which would ensure data/referential integrity, the goal of normalization

Comment: The article is not worth wasting any more time on. It talks about Transitive FDs but doesn't define FD and doesn't give us any FDs. So I'm guessing based on the sort of FDs typically found in intro articles (and on the point the article appears to be trying to make). I guess the article thinks there's an FD `fullname->salutation`. But that's not realistic: a Mr and a Dr might have the same fullname; a Ms and a Mrs and a Dr might have the same fullname (same person is unmarried then marries then qualifies). More realistic is 2 FDs `person->fullname`, `person->Salutation` also `person->Address`.

Comment: Got it thanks! It was the first article that came up on the search engine, so figured the ranking/rating must mean it's pretty good.

Comment: @Cataster & AntC "Normalisation would introduce a `Person ID`, key to a `Person` table ..." An appropriate basic straightforward design under common sense would do this. Normalization wouldn't. Normalization to higher NFs doesn't introduce new attribute names. Also "normalize" must apply to a specific table or collection of tables. It replaces a base table by smaller ones that naural join back to it. I'm sure AntC knows all this.

Comment: @Cataster Follow a (good) published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens are online free. Also DBMS reference manuals.